# Log file not created in a .NET Core application running in a Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I run a `ASP.NET Core` application in a `Docker container` and I am using `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` to write logs to a file.

I am able to see the logs when running the app locally (not in a container), but I am not able to see the logs when I bash into the container.

I am new to containerization and I was wondering if I am missing any steps.

Comment: Can you show your configuration for Serilog?

Comment: Code/Configs? And you really want log to files? The docker concept is to write logs on stdout/stderr and use a [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/). This let you collect all logs on a single point, commonly ELK in larger environments. Or use `docker logs <container>` for small plain docker setups.

Comment: What @Daniel said, but if you are going to write log files, you should be doing it on a volume mounted into your container. Otherwise, all your logs will go away when your container stops.

Comment: How did you check the log in container? Share us the detail steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow steps below to check the difference.

1. Configure `Serilog` like

   ```
       public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
               {
                   builder.AddFile("Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt");
               })
               .UseStartup<Startup>();
   ```
2. Build the image

   ```
   docker build -t dockersql .
   ```
3. Run the image

   ```
   docker run -it -p 9999:80 dockersql
   ```
4. Find the running container and exec the container

[image]

As the suggestion from @Chris, it is recommended to mount the volume, you could try like

```
    docker run -it -p 9999:80 -v D:\xx\TestDockerSQL\Test:/app/Logs dockersql
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Host :

Change folder permission to 777 where you want to store logs.

> chmod 777 .
>
> docker run -d -t -i -p 80:80 -v /usr/Logs:/app/Logs --name
> testContainer testImage